# How to use get_or_create in a way that get doesn't use all the parameters while create does?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename=perm[0],name=perm[1])
```

This piece of code is suppose to create new permissions that are not there in the database.
Now I want to get on the basis of codename but while creating I want to pass name as well.

Is there a way that I can avoid separating it into separate statements for get and create ?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the [`defaults`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) argument to `get_or_create`.

Comment: Oh! Cool. I should probably delete this question. It looks silly.

Comment: I'd suggest to keep it open, because it's a valid question. Would be good if @KevinChristopherHenry could make his comment an answer, so the question could be closed.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: Can you put your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`defaults`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) argument to `get_or_create()` allows you to make this distinction. The regular keyword parameters are used to do the lookup, while the elements of the `defaults` dictionary are only used to create a new instance (if necessary).

In your case this would look like:

```
Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename=perm[0], defaults={'name': perm[1]})
```